# Remover caracteres especiales y mostrar solo números con dos cifras en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-12

Tengo la siguiente tabla con 2 campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, el campo *Csv* tiene lo siguiente:

```
[4804300, 45, 4811044, 44, 4972440, 50, 5196488, 49]
```

Necesito quitar los corchetes y quitar el número largo y que me quede solo los números que tienen dos cifras (`45,44,50,49`) al hacer el select, es decir, solo mostrar los números que tienen dos cifras.

He encontrado esta función que quita los caracteres y letras:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tblResultado1]
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO

SELECT [dbo].[tblResultado1](Csv) 
from [dbo].[tblResultado]
```

pero me quita las comas y los corchetes, y no he podido saber cómo mostrar solo los que tienen dos dígitos.

Comment: Esa función que muestras no es válida en PostgreSQL.

Comment: Lo se, estoy intentando pasarla a PostgreSQL para que me funcione, pero no he podido, sabes de alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución sería la siguiente:

```sql
select string_agg(i, ',') 
from jsonb_array_elements_text('[10, 20, 30, 900]'::jsonb) as t(i)
where i::integer between 10 and 99
```

---

**Explicación**

1. Parsear el string a jsonb y convertir los elementos de la lista en filas (Similar a `unnest` con arrays pero para json arrays):

```sql
jsonb_array_elements_text('[10, 20, 30, 900]'::jsonb) as t(i)
```

2. Filtrar los elementos que no tengan dos cifras

```sql
where i::integer between 10 and 99
```

3. Obtener un valor agregado de strings separados por `,`:

```sql
select string_agg(i, ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

La función *translate* de *postgresql*.

Un ejemplo mío, ustedes lo hacen según necesiten:

```
UPDATE reportes.REPORTE_ALUMNOS_SANTIAGO_BNH SET lugar_nacimiento = TRIM(TRANSLATE(lugar_nacimiento,'-.,()',' ')) WHERE pais_nacimiento<>14;
```

Ahí reemplazo todos los caracteres que no quiero por espacio, en un campo determinado de una tabla determinada.